# Number of Subsets of $n$ Elements of Size $n-1$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am trying to understand why given a set of $n$ elements, there are $2^{n-1}$ subsets of size $n-1$.

Below I have written out a proof that I figured out, however I was wondering if there was a simpler way of showing the result that might be a little more intuitive. Or, perhaps, a method that made use of combinatorics.

There are $2^n$ subsets of $n$ elements, $2^n -1 $ of which contain less than $n$ elements. Additionally, there are $2^{n-1} - 1$ subsets of n elements in which each set contains less than $n-1$ elements. Thus, the number of subsets of $n$ elements of size $n-1$ is: $(2^n -1) - (2^{n-1} -1) = 2^{n-1} $

---

Comment: There are $2^n-n-1$ subsets which contain strictly fewer than $n−1$ elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not true.  Given $n$ elements, you can select $n-1$ of them in ${n \choose n-1}={n \choose 1}=n$ ways, so there are $n$ subsets of size $n-1$.  You can choose any element to leave out and you are done.

Comment: This makes sense. However, I'm not sure what the error is in my false "proof" above.

Comment: There are $2^{n-1}$ subsets of size **at most** $n-1$, not exactly equals $n-1$.

Comment: @kelvinhong方 I would have thought there were $2^n-1$ (almost double $2^{n-1}$) subsets of size at most $n-1$

Comment: @kelvinhong方:  No, there are $2^n-n-1$ subsets of size at most $n-1$.  There are $2^n$ total subsets, one is of size $n$, and $n$ are of size exactly $n-1$.

Comment: @Is12Prime:  The error in your proof is that for a given subset of $n-1$ elements there are $2^{n-1}-1$ subsets of size less than $n-1$, but there are $n$ subsets of size $n-1$.  You then multiply count the smaller subsets because they can come from different subsets of size $n-1$

Comment: @kelvinhong方:  the last comment should have been there are $2^n-n-1$ subsets of size at most $n-2$.  Yes, there are $2^n-1$ of size at most $n-1$ because only one is of size $n$.